# Is there a better way to close buttons on click?

Tags: c#, button, windows-forms-designer

I'm a beginner and have an assignment in which I must program the game of NIM.  I begin with 15 "tokens" and at each turn a maximum of three can be removed, or "hidden". So far I am hiding these tokens on click by doing the following.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Visible = false;
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Visible = false;
}
```

I simply copied and pasted that multiple times and changed the button numbers so that my buttons will close on click. This might be obvious, but is there a more efficient way to do this, instead of having 15 button close methods?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JasonB did you get your answer?

Comment: @JasonB if you get your answer accept it as answer. read  http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same click event for every single button, and make use of the sender object, casting it to `Button`:

```
private void buttonsToClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Visible = false;
}
```

Then just add that handler to every single button you want to close itself on click.

Note, though, that this will throw an `InvalidCastException` if you or anyone else uses this handler on an object that is not a `Button`, so if you're actually going to use this code I would add some sort of conditional to check the real type of the sender.

Additionally, you could reuse this for *any* `Control` object by casting sender to `Control` instead, given that `Button` inherits from `Control`, and all `Control` objects have the `Visible` property. Here's an example, with a conditional to guard against an invalid cast:

```
private void controlToMakeInvisible_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender.GetType() == typeof(Control))
    {
        ((Control)sender).Visible = false;
    }
}
```

A final note - it seems from your post like you may have a slight misunderstanding about the way events are created and wired in with objects in Windows Forms. If you go into the Designer, add a click event, and see it pop into your Form code as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

the name of this method has no bearing on its function. The button1 part of `button1_Click` doesn't actually have any logical linkage with the `Button` `button1` - it's just the default name assigned by the Designer. The actual assignment of the method `button1_Click` to the `Button.Click` event is auto-generated into your Form's Designer.cs method.

The point of this is that if you copy and paste `button1_Click` and change every incidence of `button1` with `button2`, like so:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   button2.Visible = false;
}
```

it's not going to fire when `button2` gets clicked. In actual fact, it's never going to fire at all, because the method hasn't actually been connected to any controls/events.

Comment: Might be useful to give it a more descriptive name if you are going to be doing that.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but I think you can change `object` to `Button` and still have it work (no cast that way).

Comment: You could! Another way you could do it is casting to something like UIElement, and this would work on any element with the Visibility dependency property. I'll update the post to reflect those ideas.

Comment: So, just to confirm, does this still compile if you change the method signature to `buttonsToClose_Click(Button sender, EventArgs e)` and remove the cast? I don't have VS at the moment so I can't check :(

Comment: @Asad Actually, I take that back - in Windows Forms right now it's refusing to accept (Button sender, EventArgs e) because it doesn't match System.EventHandler. Not sure whether I'm just missing something, or I've forgotten.

Comment: @furkle No, that's about right. I was thinking maybe the events themselves had been updated to use the more recent strongly typed `EventHandler<TSender>` type instead of `EventHandler`. No such luck apparently.

Comment: @Asad I think that might work in WPF, because I recall doing it before. Probably best to just handle it as object, anyway - one less exception to worry about.

Comment: @Asad there is another way for this question, check my answer.

Comment: @furkle there is another way for this question, check my answer.

Comment: @Riddle Don't comment on other people's questions begging for attention on yours.

Answer (score -1):

just call your event in a foreach loop.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        button.Click += button_Click;
    }
}

void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Control) sender).Visible = false;
}
```

if you change:

```
Controls.OfType<Button>()
```

to

```
Controls.OfType<Control>()
```

it will set visible to false for any Control. so you can control what item you want the event to be raised for easily.

OfType summary: Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

Comment: The problem with this specific implementation is that it assumes that he wants every single button in his entire application to be closed when he clicks it.

Comment: @furkle we can simply control that with a if statement in foreach and we have multiple choice for condition.